# Java TimerTask cancel doesn't work

Tags: java, timertask

Trying the TimerTask with ScheduledExecutorService.
Schedule a task with delay 10 sec, and call task.cancel.
But the task still run, not sure what happen, and if the cancel method doesn't seems to do any cancelling.
Please help.

```
package xxx.xxx;

import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Tester {

    static class OrderWaveTask extends TimerTask{
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("hi");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ScheduledExecutorService orderWaveTP = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
        TimerTask task = new Tester.OrderWaveTask();
        orderWaveTP.schedule(task, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("cancelling task: "+ task.cancel());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ScheduledFuture to cancel the task. Change your code to following should make it work.

```
ScheduledFuture<?> future = orderWaveTP.schedule(task, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("cancelling task: "+ future.cancel(false));
```

Answer (score 1):

The TimerTask is meant to be used with a Timer class in order to schedule executions and support cancellation.

When you schedule a TimerTask via an Executor, you're really just telling the executor to run a Runnable, and control is performed by the Executor; it has no idea that you're running a TimerTask, so the TimerTask functions have no effect.

Your choices would be to use a Timer instead of an ExecutorService, or use the ExecutorService methods to cancel execution.